# Tabhost load all the tabs?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am creating a tabhost with 3 tabs but it is loading all the tabs at same time .. I want to load only selected tab ?

Please help

Code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Resources ressources = getResources(); 
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 





    // Users tab
            Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, UsersOnMap.class);
            TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
              .newTabSpec("Users On Map")
              .setContent(intentAndroid);
            tabSpecAndroid.setIndicator("Users On Map",getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map));

            tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);     


     //Users List

            Intent intentAndroid1 = new Intent().setClass(this, UserList.class);
            TabSpec tabSpecAndroid1 = tabHost
              .newTabSpec("Users List")
              .setContent(intentAndroid1);
            tabSpecAndroid1.setIndicator("Users List",getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_sort_by_size));

            tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid1);     



    //History tab
            Intent intentBus = new Intent().setClass(this, History.class);
            TabSpec tabSpecBus = tabHost
                    .newTabSpec("History")
                    .setContent(intentBus);
            tabSpecBus.setIndicator("History",getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer));
            tabHost.addTab(tabSpecBus);   


            int his=getIntent().getIntExtra("his", 0);

            if(his==1)
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);





}
```

Comment: then switch to fragments

Comment: do you have sample code

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/